# PHP generate ticket for queue system and able to reset the ticket number on the next day

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use php to make a simple queue system where a ticket will generate when customer choose an option. The main requirements are:

1. Generate ticket number with the format (eg. C0001, E0001), the alphabet represent different option the customer choose.
2. Able to reset the number for the next day (staff click the reset button).
3. Each records need to be stored in mysql.

Below are what I got, I got two table (ticket_id and ticket) and one trigger:

**ticket_id**

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket_id` (`ticket_id` int(5) NOT NULL)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**ticket**

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket` (`ticket_id` int(5) NOT NULL, 
`ticket_name` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''0''',
`ticket_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`ticket_time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_ticket_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `ticket`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ticket_id VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.ticket_name = CONCAT('A', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 4, '0'));
END
```

**newTicket**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_type, ticket_time)
          VALUES ('$in_tickettype', NOW())
          ";
```

**reset**

```
$query = "UPDATE ticket SET
          ticket_name = DEFAULT
          WHERE ticket_time = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ";
```

The trigger works well as it successfully generate the number, but I don't know **how to reset the number**. Anyway I know trigger is not the only option to get the whole thing done, if anyone got any better solutions please help me.